# I am not able to fix a code issue in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to define 2 functions, but only `has_33` is working and `myfunction` is not working.

I am trying this code in jupyter notebook:

```
def myfunction(num):
    for i in range(0, len(num)-1):
        if num[i:i+2] == [3,3]:
            return True
        return False
```

and this code:

```
def has_33(nums):
    for i in range(0, len(nums)-1):
        if nums[i:i+2] == [3,3]:
            return True  
    return False
```

`myfunction([1,2,4,3,3])` should give true but it is giving false result but `has_33([1,2,4,3,3])` is giving the true result. Why is this happening?

Comment: It is because of indentation. In `myfunction`, if the condition `num[0:2] == [3,3]` is not satisfied, then the function immediately returns False. Whereas in `has_33`, it iterates through entire list and then only will return False if there are no consecutive `[3,3]`.

Comment: @AneeshPalsule: Perhaps you could write up your comment as an answer.

Comment: @quamrana The problem with writing this as an answer is that the underlying indentation problem is duplicated ad nauseam and is little more than a typo (made by someone who doesn't realize the significance of such typos)

Comment: @JohnColeman: Yes, I wish that something could be done about this eternal problem. But in the mean time there is another user that needs encouragement.

Comment: @quamrana part of the problem is that even though this bug pops up all the time, there is seldom a good duplicate target (especially one which the person asking the problem could be reasonably expected to find). If they knew to search for indentation then they would be able to solve their own problem without asking.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there is indent difference in both code:
in first function second return is inside of for loop where as in second function it is out of for loop:

So in first function when if condition is false and it is going on second return and returning false for first value 0

In second function if evaluation keep false till i is 3 and for loop is not executing return. Once if evaluation become true on i=0 it is executing return of if and returning true so control goes out of function and second return out of for is not getting executed:

corrected first function:

```
def myfunction(num):
    for i in range(0,len(num)-1):
        if num[i:i+2] == [3,3]:
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Indentation error! Just needed to erase a whitespace from the last line of your first code. The for loop will return False now. Try like this:

```
def myfunction(num):  
    for i in range(0,len(num)-1):  
        if num[i:i+2] == [3,3]:  
            return True  
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting my comment as an answer as suggested by @quamrana.

This behavior is because of indentation. In `myfunction`, if the condition `nums[0:2] == [3,3]` is not satisfied, then the function immediately returns `False`. Whereas in `has_33`, it iterates through entire list and then only will return `False` if there are no consecutive `[3,3]`.

e.g.

```
nums = [1,2,3,3,5]

myfunction(nums)
False
```

#### Let's go step by step in the function

1. > `for i in range(0,len(num)-1)`

   `i` is initialized to `0`, i.e. `i = 0`.
2. > `nums[i:i+2]`

   Since `i` is `0`, becomes `nums[0:2]` i.e. `[nums[0], nums[1]]`.
3. > `if num[i:i+2] == [3,3]`

   Becomes `if num[0:2] == [3,3]`. Since `nums[0] = 1` and `nums[1] = 2`, `[nums[0], nums[1]] != [3,3]`. Thus, `if` block will not be executed.
4. Since `return False` is in the `for` loop and `if` condition was not satisfied, the next line is executed, which is `return False`. The function execution stops here.

Now, second function:

```
nums = [1,2,3,3,5]

has_33(nums)
True
```

#### Step by step

1. Same as myfunction.
2. Same as myfunction.
3. Same as myfunction.
4. Now here is the catch. Since `return False` is written outside `for` loop, `i` increases by `1`.
   `i = 1`
5. `nums[i:i+2]` is `nums[1:3]` which is `[nums[1], nums[2]]`.
6. The loop continues until you get a `[3,3]` OR `i = len(nums) - 1`.

Hope this helps you understand what went wrong.